# Chrome issuing GET requests for images already loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a JS game for Facebook and preloading all images. With chrome, but not yet seen on other browsers, once I open a new tab and surf a few sites chrome will issue fresh GET requests for images already in cache and on screen.

For the sake of testing I put ALL the images, at a 20x20 pixels size, on the side of the game. But if I open a new tab, then surf the web for 5 or so minutes, images that were not in the main game div will get reloaded when they get added to the page again (even though they are sitting on screen in a 'preloaded' div).

Rails 3.2 backend on Heroku.

I have tried disabling all Chrome plugins, clearing the cache, and a few different preloader strategies.

**resolved**

The page was caching fine, the images weren't. I added the following line to my rails production.rb, and the problem appears fixed.

Comment: you should make sure chrome has been assured that the images *should* be cached. If you aren't familiar with how to specify this via http headers, [have a read](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/). Otherwise, you will surely see varying behavior from browser to browser.

Comment: also, browsers have limited cache sizes. They often purge old entries to make room as newer cachable entries are encountered, even if the old entries should be cached for a long time.

Comment: I tried setting max-age to 2 hours and it makes no difference. It actually does it about 1 minute after opening the page once I surf a few other pages. And I cleared the cache, so it wasn't full.

I'm pretty sure it's something do do with chrome and JS generated content, but I'm running out of ideas to try. Cheers though.

Comment: OK, my bad. The page was caching fine, the images weren't. I added the following line to my rails production.rb, and the problem appears fixed!

'config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=7200"'

Comment: Post it as answer, and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page was caching fine, the images weren't. I added the following line to my rails production.rb, and the problem appears fixed.

```
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=7200"
```

Thanks @chris for getting me on the right track!

Comment: If you ever need to update the images, make sure you use a different URL.  Otherwise they'll continue to be cached and the site visitors (game players) won't get the updated version of the images.